# Temporary Variable Assistance (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

I'm making a random sentence generator using Scheme (Pretty Big), and I'm having trouble defining temporary variables. I want to make something like this:

```
<NOUN1> <VERB1> <NOUN2> <but> <NOUN2> <VERB1> <NOUN2> <also>
```

Example: Sharks eat fish, but fish eat fish also. 
I have word lists, and functions to choose a word from said list. Then, I use append to create a function. I am able to do:

```
(define (sentence) 
  (append (getNoun) '(and) (getNoun) (getVerb)))
```

However, I am unable to figure out a way to temporarily define a variable. 
I have this so far:

```
(define (sentence1) 
  (append (getNoun)
          (lambda (verb getVerb)
            (noun getNoun))
          (verb) (noun) '(but) (noun) (verb) (noun)))
```

Hints/Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `let`.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html

Here is an example usage:

```
(define (my-proc age)
  (let ([age-plus-10 (+ age 10)])
    (printf "age is ~a" age)
    (printf "age-plus-10 is ~a" age-plus-10)))
```

Notice how we can temporarily define age-plus-10 and then use it later.